# <Prefer> in conditionals in reference to future

Tags: grammar

Hello everyone:

Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

Situation: A friend of mine has come to me for advice:

a.  I **would prefer it** if you **would come** on another day; I am really busy today.

b.  I **would have preferred it** if you **had come** on a different day; I am really busy today.

c.  I **would have preferred it** if you **came on** another day;........

Thanks

Comment: It is best to limit posts to a single question rather than a series of questions. With no specific context or discussion of a particular aspect of English that is confusing to you, this is simple proofreading.

Comment: It IS a single question. It is about the patterns with the word ''prefer'' when used in reference to future.

Comment: It is not a single question, because it does not have a single answer. Any response would have to address each of these cases individually. The question asks about seven completely different constructions that happen to use the verb "prefer".

Comment: Okay. Then, I am going to narrow it down to only the conditional sentences with "prefer".

Answer (score 1):

**All three are correct**. The second and third phrases are in the past tense, and the first is in the present.